# Change mic jack to headphone jack?

Tags: audio, windows-registry

I know this is possible using a registry tweak but I've been unable to find it again. Anyone know it? Using this for an asus eeepc 1005ha

Comment: Unlikely thats its even possible

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/561561/how-to-use-front-panel-mic-in-jack-as-headset-out-jack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use front panel mic-in jack as headset out jack?](https://superuser.com/questions/561561/how-to-use-front-panel-mic-in-jack-as-headset-out-jack)

Answer (score 4):

This depends entirely on your (built-in) sound card.

The microphone and headphone jacks are hardwired to the sound card. **If and only if** the manufacturer allows switching somehow, it's possible. If not, there's nothing the OS can do about it.

For example, [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) calls this technique *connector retasking*. If your sound card supports it, you can retask your connectors with the *Realtek Audio Manager*. If applicable, this software should accompany your sound card / motherboard.

For other brands, consult your sound card's / motherboard's manual.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not all mobos support this feature directly - hence the need for a registry tweak...

Comment: If the motherboard doesn't support it (at all), it's simply not possible. You cannot rewire your headphone jack in software.

Comment: I've gotten it working this way before. It's definitely possible. Only issue I had was realtek kicking it back to being a mic - had to uninstall it.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's possible with (some) Realtek cards, because they built / wired the jacks that way. The only reason this "hack" works is because it introduces the exact same registry key that the Audio Manager would introduce. But there's no **universal** registry key that will retask your jacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use a mic jack as a headphone jack and you don't necessarily have to mess with the registry.

I have a Asus motherboard and used Realtek HD Audio manager to change it. Turns out you can click the pink mic circle inside Realtek HD Audio manager and reconfigure it to headphones. Oh and this only worked for my front mic jack not the rear one.