# How to use front panel mic-in jack as headset out jack?

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers

I'm using Windows 8, and my cabinet's front panel headset jack has broken down. So I was thinking to use the "mic-in" jack as the 'headset" (line-out) jack.

How do I achieve this without having to install the Realtek sound driver?

**Edit :**

I was asking if it was possible to reconfigure the jacks at **software level**.

> Here is a method that can be used to reconfigure the jacks, but it
>   requires realtek drivers to be installed.

http://www.reaper-x.com/2012/02/13/how-to-remap-retasking-realtek-onboard-jacks-ports/

So I wanted to know if the same can be achieved without having to install realtek drivers.

Comment: How has it "broken down"? Does your system support remapping of the audio ports? Do you believe that the Realtek sound driver can solve your problem? Why wouldn't you want to install the sound driver? Are you using a different sound driver?

Comment: I suggest you add some additional information - what is your motherboard model? Are you certain your motherboard provides for remapping of ports via software at all? If so, there are probably drivers from the motherboard mfr that do the job - or maybe in your BIOS. Have you checked?

Comment: Latest realtek drivers which I used to use on xp supports remapping of jacks. The reason I'm not using realtek driver anymore is because they used to cause static noise, which goes away when i use windows default sound drivers.

Comment: did you check if your BIOS supports re-mapping?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can repurpose these jacks using software, or by simply making changes in the driver options. This is all quite low-level.

The only solution I can see working would be to (somehow) connect the front "mic-in" jack to different headers on the motherboard (the ones that corresponded to the front headphone jack).

Should be pretty easy to do:

[image]

Comment: If OP is planning to open the case, then it may be wiser to consider actually replacing the broken socket, instead of rewiring.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about your case or motherboard, this information may be of some basic assistance: [Installing Front Panel Audio Plugs](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/93).  **I strongly** recommend you refer to your motherboard manual before attempting to change any connections on your motherboard.  Take all necessary precautions including disconnecting mains connections and taking care not to touch any static sensitive parts or tracks.  Remember that the website reference will probably not reflect the pin configuration of your motherboard - **read your manual!**

Comment: I was asking if it was possible at the software level and not hardware level. May be some driver or registry tweak.

Answer (score 2):

The Realtek are the best and easiest way to configure your audio jacks.  The Realtek drivers do make it possible to set the audio output to the mic in/line in jack on the front and rear panel.

Open the Realtek HD Audio Manager.  In the top left corner choose the underlined option Device Advanced Settings. If you are dead set against using Realtek drivers look at this link.  [How to remap / retasking Realtek onboard jacks / ports](http://www.reaper-x.com/2012/02/13/how-to-remap-retasking-realtek-onboard-jacks-ports/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you won't be able to do this without opening your computer and rewiring the sockets.  The circuitry to which the mic-in socket is connected isn't able to generate line-out signals.

Comment: On some sound cards, it's possible to configure inputs and outputs through software, but if that's true for OP's card, then the only way is to do it through their own software as there is no common API for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

without a proper audio driver you can't do this, if you don't need to install a audio driver then, solution explained by Flup will greatly work.
if you have audio driver installed then `retasking` the port will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** remap the wiring with some technical mechanical finesse and in some cases the software, but not likely the mic. If your mic has a boost option, you theoretically have power to the port but that doesn't mean that engineers have made this possible.

I'm investigating this possibility on Drv7083_DevType_0272_SS10250487, but it doesn't seem likely.

You will be able to do this with almost any driver as their revisions have more to do with dll's, rather than the registry, but you never know.